# How do I rewrite my SQL query to remove redundant values from a GROUP BY column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, distinct

I am working on a project that aims to deliver a system where you can analyse data from an SQL table. I am making this query (inside a VB.NET program) to get the required data into a GridView:

```
SELECT [task], [activity], SUM([consumption]) AS TotalMin 
FROM [TimeTable]
WHERE [name]=@name 
   AND [month]=@month 
   AND [year]=@year 
GROUP BY [task], [activity]
ORDER BY [task] ASC
```

What I get is this:

```
task        | activity | TotalMin
------------+----------+---------
new website | meeting  | 60
new website | planing  | 240
new website | testing  | 340
new app     | meeting  | 60
new app     | planing  | 240
new app     | testing  | 340
```

Is it somehow possible to not repeat the task for every activity so it just displays the task once and then just every activity related to that task listed below?

The desired output is:

```
task        | activity | TotalMin
------------+----------+---------
new website | meeting  | 60
            | planing  | 240
            | testing  | 340
new app     | meeting  | 60
            | planing  | 240
            | testing  | 340
```

Comment: You've used (among others) the `vb.net` tag. How is that programming language relevant to your question? You've only posted a SQL query here…?

Comment: Well as mentioned in the original post the select statement is used to fill the GridView with data which is a vb.net component.

Comment: Yes, but it appears that VB.NET, nor the GridView for that matter, is actually irrelevant to your question. Your question is about how to change the query so that you will get a different result. Can you give an example for the desired result?

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the feedback :)
I have updated the post with the desired output :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this in your query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [task] ORDER BY [task]) = 1 THEN [task] ELSE '' END as [task],
 [activity], SUM([consumption]) AS TotalMin 
FROM [TimeTable]
WHERE [name]=@name 
   AND [month]=@month 
   AND [year]=@year 
GROUP BY [task], [activity]
ORDER BY [task] ASC
```

This query uses [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.100).aspx) function to group related tasks together assigning each a sequential row number. And displays actual task only for the row 1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works by removing the ORDER BY Statement :)

Comment: @RomanParhiz, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: @AHiggins Done! I appreciate all the help I got :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding the grid to a DataTable, and this was the requirement given to me, I would probably modify the contents of the DataTable before binding.

Iterating through a collection of rows is pretty trivial in VB.NET...

```
For Each r As DataRow in MyDataTable.Rows()
```

Inside the loop, you'd compare the task name to the task name of the previous row.  If it's the same as the previous row, you'd change it to the empty string.

Please note that this is a brute force hack, and that there is probably a more elegant way to accomplish the desired goal.  However, elegant is not always the best and brute force is not always the worst. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are absolutely right. But before doing that I wanted to know if it was possible using SQL alone.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure it's possible through SQL alone, but there's no --right-- way to solve this problem.  Use whatever solution serves your needs and the needs of your application.  Also, if you go with the brute-force approach, leave a few comments in the code so the next developer will know what you did and why. :)